# Continuous operators

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

We have that $T:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is linear where $E$ is a normed space  we have that $\ker T=\{x\in E, Tx=0\}=T^{-1}(\{0\})$ if we suppose that $\ker T$ is closed, as $\{0\}$ is closed can we conclude that $T$ is continuous  ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T$ is not continuous. So $T$ is not bounded. i.e. $\exists$ a sequence $x_n$ such that $T(x_n) \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. Let $a\notin \ker T$. Then defining $$x_n' = a - \frac{T(a)}{T(x_n)}x_n ,$$ it is clear that $T(x_n') = 0$ and so $x_n'\in \ker T$. Also $x_n' \to a \notin \ker T.$ So $\ker T$ is not closed.  Hence $\ker T$ closed implies that $T$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you but is my proof is correct ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou No, your argument shows $T$ continuous implies kernel closed, but the reverse is not always true for all operators, but it is for functionals.

Comment: But we suppose that $\ker T$ is closed , the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ is closed @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @HennoBrandsma and in this case $T$ is a functional no ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou yes, so we need the extra argument that we both gave. You cannot conclude in general that if $\ker{T}$ is closed, then $T$ is continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what is the extra argument ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou see my answer, or the answer above, which are essentially the same.

Comment: so my answer is not sufficient @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @HennoBrandsma can you give me an example of $T:E\rightarrow R$ not continious but $\ker T$ is closed with $E$ a normed space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40282/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-vrouvrou).

Comment: you are not in the descussion @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @HennoBrandsma are you there please

Comment: @HennoBrandsma is m proof schow that $T$ is continuous on $0$

Answer (score 1):

We can. Suppose $T$ is not continuous, then $T$ is not bounded, so there is some sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ such that $T(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$. We can assume WLOG that all $T(x_n) \neq 0$.

We surely have some $p \notin \ker{T}$ (otherwise $T \equiv 0$), and so we can define $y_n = p - \frac{T(p)}{T(x_n)}x_n$, where the fraction is a well-defined scalar. Then $T(y_n) = T(p) - \frac{T(p)}{T(x_n)}T(x_n) = T(p) - T(p) = 0$, so $y_n \in \ker{T}$ for all $n$, and $y_n \rightarrow p$ as the coefficients of $x_n$ tend to $0$. So we have a sequence $(y_n)$ from the kernel that converges to $p$ not in the kernel, so the kernel is not closed. So $T$ is continuous.